# how to work on pagination into grid view in android?

Tags: android, pagination

how to work on pagination into gridview in android.provide sample code for this.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing in the Android SDK for this. You will need to write your own widget.

Comment: anything news for this?

Answer (score 0):

Since the introduction of the Compatibility pack, there is a solution within Android. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4449416/android-pagination-in-gridview/7875459#7875459).