# android pagination in gridview

Tags: android, gridview, pagination

Is it possible pagination in android gridview? if it is available can you provide any link.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to work on pagination into grid view in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448437/how-to-work-on-pagination-into-grid-view-in-android)

Comment: See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679136/custom-gridview-in-android/9679281#9679281

Answer (score 2):

For horizontal paging, use a GridView inside a ViewPager. [Here is a tutorial](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html).